# Using Array objects later on without knowing it's position

Tags: arrays, powershell, foreach

I'm running following line of code to loop through all my Azure subscription saving vms in all subscription to array. Can I somehow query data from that array based on vm name so it would display all available data? Would need save that specific vm data on variable so I can use and parse it later.

```
 $VM = @()
    $AllSubscriptions = Get-AzSubscription
    foreach ($Subscription in $AllSubscriptions) {
        write-host "Count of subscriptions to loop:" $AllSubscriptions.length
        Set-AzContext $Subscription.Id | Out-Null
        Write-Host "Checking subscription $($Subscription.Name) for vm details"
        $VM += Get-AzVM -Status 
    }

    $VM
```

$vm results format
[image: $vm results]

Tried following commands but did not work for me:

```
$vm -like '*server01*'
```

This displayed only vm name, no additional information was available

```
$vm.name -like '*server01*'
```

This displayed right information but position can change and there can be several vms to be queried. So maybe somehow put '6' to variable..?

```
$vm[6]
```

Comment: Try `$vm | Where-Object{$_.name -like '*nalle45*'} | Select *`

Comment: that did the work! Than you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below, it will filter the object by the name and output the whole object.

```
$vm | Where-Object {$_.name -like '*nalle45*'} | Select *
```